# Calling another GUI from a file in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-import

Suppose I have one GUI with a simple code as follows
It has a button on it and when this is clicked I want to have another GUI to pop-up and then call the function from it. The problem is that when I run the first file, the GUI of the other one automatically pop-up. What should I do.

The code of the `first` file is as follows

```
from tkinter import *
import another

root = Tk()

button1 = Button(root, text = "Call" , command = another.abc)
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

The code of second file `another.py` is as follows

```
from tkinter import *

root_Test2 = Tk()
root_Test2.geometry('450x450')

def abc():
     print("that's working")


root_Test2.mainloop()
```

Please suggest the solution that help me to open the second window when the button on the first one is clicked

Comment: To import one .py file into another you need to structure it properly as a [module](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) so that the code doesn't get run when you import it.

Comment: can you suggest the changes, I have to make in second file so that mainloop() of the second don't get called

Comment: If you've read that tutorial article I linked you to, you should be able to figure that out for yourself. It's not just the `mainloop` that shouldn't get run, the `root_Test2 = Tk()` and `root_Test2.geometry('450x450')` shouldn't get run either. Only the Tkinter import and the `abc` function definition can get executed. The other stuff _must_ be protected inside a `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.

Comment: So have a go at doing that, and if you _still_ can't figure it out, edit the code in your question to show your latest attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @PM 2Ring, You can change your second file's code to this:

```
from tkinter import *
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root_Test2 = Tk()
    root_Test2.geometry('450x450')

def abc():
     print("that's working")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root_Test2.mainloop()
```

You can find further information about `if __name__ == '__main__'` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)